# The construction « plus... , plus... » "the more... , the more..."

Tags: grammaire

> **Plus** tu détiens de ces/les pavés, **plus** nombreux sont les sorts auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir.

A couple of points I can’t find answers for, even after referring to some similar posts in the past:

1. When I want to say "the more of **these/those/the** tomes you have" instead of "the more tomes you have", is it acceptable to say "plus tu détiens de **ces/les** pavés" instead of "plus tu détiens de pavés"?
2. In the second half, I opted to use inversion due to the long subject. But for the sake of argument, if the subject were the pronoun "**ils**", should I say "plus ils sont nombreux" without inversion?
3. If you swap the noun "pavé" with "pain", for instance, do you still need to pluralise the word, like "plus tu manges de **pains**"? Or is it more like "plus tu manges de **pain**"? The same question goes for the noun "eau".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **de ces** does the trick perfectly. **de les** would become **des**... but it sounds strange, I think you cannot translate **the** in this case, it would be **de** but it's more a translation for **of tomes**.
2. In this same case you could say: **plus les sorts auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir sont nombreux** ; with **ils** I can't find a correct sentence. **plus ils sont nombreux auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir** sounds really incorrect to me.
   EDIT - You must replace **les sorts** with **ceux** and not **ils**: **Plus tu détiens de ces pavés, plus nombreux sont ceux auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir**. Of course **ceux** seems to refer to **les pavés** in this context, so you must be careful.
3. Don't pluralise it (**pain** or **eau**). You can say **de ce pain** or **de cette eau** if you want to translate **of this bread** or **of this water**. If you want to say **some breads among others** or **some waters among others** (it can have sense in some contexts) like for the tomes, you pluralise it but it's not exactly the same meaning, like in English I suppose.

Comment: Re #3 I think it's fine to pluralize *pain* if talking about individual-sized loaves

Comment: For #2, if we already know that we are talking about _sorts auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir_ , we can say _Plus tu détiens de ces pavés, plus ils sont nombreux._

Comment: @qoba Yes that's what I wanted to mean, maybe I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Gwen Sure but the OP wanted to replace the subject by 'ils'. In your example, you truncated the part 'auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir'.

Comment: As I said, It's possible to use 'ils' **if we already know what we are talking about**, and in this case it's not truncated because previously said. For example: _Chaque livre de magie te donne accès à un sort. Pour l'instant, il n'y a que peu de sorts auxquels tu es autorisé à recourir. Plus tu détiens de ces pavés, plus ils sont nombreux._ (assuming pavé means book here).

Comment: You are totally changing the construction of the sentence, so of course it's possible to use 'ils' in this case... This isn't the question at all. The question is: if the subject is 'ils' and not 'les sorts' (we don't care why it's *ils* and we don't care if we already know what it refers to, it's just for the sake of argument), should I still use the construction *adjective + verb + subject* like in *nombreux sont les sorts* or should I use *ils sont nombreux*. And the answer is you cannot use *ils* with this construction.

Comment: @LUNA Edited, I realized you must use **ceux** and not **ils** if you want to keep the construction.